# Multiple elements moving circularly - smooth transition

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, css-transitions

I'm attempting to create a circular navigation with `n` elements navigable by clicking the keyboard's right and left arrows. I use classes with specific CSS3 `rotate` and `translate` values and a little bit of javascript in order to change the classes to do so.

[image]

**My problem** is that the transition between elements with classes `four` and `five`, the one that translates between `360deg` and `30deg`, which goes in the opposite direction than I want it to. You can see the obvious unwanted behavior [**here in this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/jGAze/3/)

```
.one    { transform: rotate(270deg) translate(200px); }
.two    { transform: rotate(300deg) translate(200px); }
.three  { transform: rotate(330deg) translate(200px); }
.four   { transform: rotate(360deg) translate(200px); }<-- Problematic transition
.five   { transform: rotate(30deg)  translate(200px); }<-- Problematic transition
.six    { transform: rotate(60deg)  translate(200px); }
.seven  { transform: rotate(90deg)  translate(200px); }
.eight  { transform: rotate(120deg) translate(200px); }
.nine   { transform: rotate(150deg) translate(200px); }
.ten    { transform: rotate(180deg) translate(200px); }
.eleven { transform: rotate(210deg) translate(200px); }
.twelve { transform: rotate(240deg) translate(200px); }
```

I would prefer a CSS fix for this, but I also attempted a javascript one which can be found [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/jGAze/5/). I only attempted using the left arrow in this example. My approach with javascript is to obtain the current translated value in string form, strip the `rotate` degree from it, and add or subtract 30 degrees from it depending on whether or not the right or left arrow is pressed. The current problem with this approach is that it does not give me a value for `element.style.webkitTransform` (I'm using the Chrome), it's just empty for some reason. Also I'd prefer not to have to prefix everything in the javascript, thus the reason why I would like a CSS only fix

My attempt at the javascript (untested because the first line won't work for some reason):

```
var thisTransform = circleArray[i].style.webkitTransform;
if (thisTransform.indexOf("rotate(") >= 0) {
    var newDeg = parseInt(thisTransform.split("rotate(")[1].substring(thisTransform.indexOf("deg"))) - 30;
    circleArray[i].style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + newDeg + "deg) translate(200px) !important;";
}
```

Side note: I use prefixfree.min.js in my project to prevent form having to manually input all of the browser prefixes

Is there a CSS only fix for my problem that I am unaware of? What is causing the error when attempting to obtain the `translate` value using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let me say that I think that probably the best solution would be just rotate the base circle; I am almost sure that the results would be better and easier.

But this is just an by side idea, let's go to the problem that you post.

I have done a workaroud to your problem creating a class that will move correctly the problematic classes. My idea is to provide an animation that does the movement  ok:

```
.foura   { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(200px); 
    -webkit-animation: aclock .3s linear 1;
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(200px); 
    animation: aclock .3s linear 1;
    transition: none;
}
@keyframes aclock {
    0% {transform: rotate(30deg) translate(200px);}
   100% {transform: rotate(0deg) translate(200px);}
}
```

The idea is that the movement from 30 deg to 360 deg, being done thru an animation, can be changed to go from 30 deg to 0 deg.

I provide another similar class for class five.

The remaining problem is that the script must set the element to class four or foura depending on the rotation sense, and the same for five and fivea.

This lead to that (somewhat messy) script:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    switch(e.which || e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            for (var i = 0, j = circleArray.length; i < j; i++) {
                var curClassList = circleArray[i].classList,
                    curClass = curClassList.toString().split(' ')[1];
                    baseClass = curClass;
                    if (baseClass == "fivea") {
                        baseClass = "five";
            }
                    if (baseClass  == "foura") {
                        baseClass  = "four";
            }

                if(circleClassArray.indexOf(baseClass) - 1 >= 0)
                {
                    var newClass = circleClassArray[circleClassArray.indexOf(baseClass) - 1];
                    if (newClass == "four") {
                        newClass = "foura";
            }
                    curClassList.add(newClass)
                    curClassList.remove(curClass);
                } else {
                    curClassList.add(circleClassArray[j - 1]);
                    curClassList.remove(curClass);
                }
            }
            break;
        case 39:
            for (var i = 0, j = circleArray.length; i < j; i++) {
                var curClassList = circleArray[i].classList,
                    curClass = curClassList.toString().split(' ')[1];
                    baseClass = curClass;
                    if (baseClass == "fivea") {
                        baseClass = "five";
            }
                    if (baseClass  == "foura") {
                        baseClass  = "four";
            }
                if(circleClassArray.indexOf(baseClass) + 1 < j)
                {
                    var newClass = circleClassArray[circleClassArray.indexOf(baseClass) + 1];
                    if (newClass == "five") {
                        newClass = "fivea";
            }
                    curClassList.add(newClass)
                    curClassList.remove(curClass);
                } else {
                    curClassList.add(circleClassArray[0]);
                    curClassList.remove(curClass);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And this is the full CSS:

```
.circle-big {
    position: relative;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background:red;
    border-radius: 50% 50%;
    margin: 10% 10%;
    border:5px solid black;
}
.circle-inner {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top:-155px;
    margin-left:-155px;
}
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top:-35px;
    margin-left:-35px;
    transition: all .3s linear;
}
.one    { -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(200px); 
          transform: rotate(270deg) translate(200px); 
          background:blue; }
.two    { -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) translate(200px); 
          transform: rotate(300deg) translate(200px); }
.three  { -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) translate(200px);
          transform: rotate(330deg) translate(200px);
}
.four   { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(200px);
          transform: rotate(360deg) translate(200px);}
.foura   { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(200px); 
          -webkit-animation: aclock .3s linear 1;
          transform: rotate(360deg) translate(200px); 
          animation: aclock .3s linear 1;
          transition: none;
}
.five   { -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg)  translate(200px);
          transform: rotate(30deg)  translate(200px);}
.fivea   { -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg)  translate(200px); 
          -webkit-animation: clock .3s linear 1;
          transform: rotate(30deg)  translate(200px); 
          animation: clock .3s linear 1;
          transition: none;
}
.six    { -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg)  translate(200px);
          transform: rotate(60deg)  translate(200px);}
.seven  { -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)  translate(200px);
           transform: rotate(90deg)  translate(200px);}
.eight  { -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) translate(200px);
          transform: rotate(120deg) translate(200px);}
.nine   { -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) translate(200px); 
          transform: rotate(150deg) translate(200px); }
.ten    { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(200px); 
          transform: rotate(180deg) translate(200px);}
.eleven { -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) translate(200px);
          transform: rotate(210deg) translate(200px);}
.twelve { -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) translate(200px);
          transform: rotate(240deg) translate(200px);}

@-webkit-keyframes clock {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(200px);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(200px);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes aclock {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(200px);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate(200px);}
}

@keyframes clock {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg) translate(200px);}
  100% {transform: rotate(30deg) translate(200px);}
}

@keyframes aclock {
    0% {transform: rotate(30deg) translate(200px);}
  100% {transform: rotate(0deg) translate(200px);}
}
```

## [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/jGAze/15/)

Following my first idea, I have added the  following code to the script:

```
   case 38:
    angle = angle + 30;
    var circleBig = document.getElementsByClassName("circle-big")[0];
    var style = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
    circleBig.style.webkitTransform = style;
    break;
case 40:
    angle = angle - 30;
    var circleBig = document.getElementsByClassName("circle-big")[0];
    var style = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
    circleBig.style.webkitTransform = style;
    break;
```

And added also transition to the big circle. Now I think it works ok (on up and down arrow !)

## [second version](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/jGAze/17/)

## Brand new version

For the new requirement (to keep the inner circles upright) I have redesigned most of the fiddle. I have adapted an idea that I saw from Lea Verou, to make the rotation without auxiliar divs. It consists in setting the transform to angle + translation + oposite angle. That makes the div go where you want, unrotated.

Once decided to go this way, the script has to modified the styles of the inner circles, and not the style of the base circle. To do that easily, I have stored in every element the angle of that particular element (in a data- property).

## [Brand New demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BWV3d/)

The resulting HTML is similiar:

```
<div class="circle-big">
    <div class="circle one" data-angle=270>1</div>
    <div class="circle two" data-angle=300>2</div>
    <div class="circle three" data-angle=330>3</div>
    <div class="circle four" data-angle=0>4</div>
    <div class="circle five" data-angle=30>5</div>
    <div class="circle six" data-angle=60>6</div>
    <div class="circle seven" data-angle=90>7</div>
    <div class="circle eight" data-angle=120>8</div>
    <div class="circle nine" data-angle=150>9</div>
    <div class="circle ten" data-angle=180>10</div>
    <div class="circle eleven" data-angle=210>11</div>
    <div class="circle twelve" data-angle=240>12</div>
    <div class="circle-inner"></div>
</div>
```

And the script is

```
var circleArray = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
var angle = 0;

window.onload = chargearray;

function chargearray () {
    for (var i = 0, j = circleArray.length; i < j; i++) {
        var circle = circleArray[i];
        var circleAngle = parseInt (circle.dataset.angle);
        var totalAngle = angle + circleAngle
        var style = "rotate(" + totalAngle + "deg) translate(200px)";
        totalAngle = - totalAngle;
        style = style + " rotate(" + totalAngle + "deg)"
        circle.style.webkitTransform = style;
        circle.style.Transform = style;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    switch(e.which || e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            angle = angle + 30;
            chargearray ();
            break;
        case 39:
            angle = angle - 30;
            chargearray ();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution, +1! It works perfectly when a button is clicked and the transition is given plenty of time to finish. That being said, if the arrows are clicked before the transition is done it has another behavior I wish to avoid. Any help with that, besides restricting the arrows from being clicked during that transition period? I would love to try and just rotate the base circle with the other circles attached to it, but I am unsure how to position the elements and bind them to the parent in the positions they are currently set in. Any help with that idea?

Comment: The jumpiness I mentioned in the comment above is the reason why I was trying to stay away from CSS animations

Comment: Really, I don't know how to fix the jumpiness caused by a nervous user. I have added another solution, based on my first idea of rotating the base circle. I am noticing now that I have only included webkit translation, sorry about that !

Comment: I don't mind the only webkit translation, as I said I use a prefixer anyway. And thank you for the second version! That is exactly what I was looking for in my attempt at a javascript fix, only you took away the need for the part that was giving me an error. I just took your work and took out the unnecessary parts to clean it up a bit http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/jGAze/18/ (for others who may be interested in using it)

Comment: Glad to help you. By the way, when you get the current value of a transform, it is always in matrix format; it is not trivial to convert it back to rotation. Much better to keep it in a variable in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I am trying to fully understand CSS animation and transformations as seen in the projects I work on and the questions I've asked recently

Comment: On a side note, is there an easier way to keep the smaller circles upright than adding an div around each one and rotating the container div the opposite direction each time? I am using a for loop to do that currently

Comment: Added another version, that keeps the circles upright. Idea taken from Lea Verou. If you don't know who she is, I recomend you to see some videos of her presentations.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all your help! I can truthfully say this is the most helpful answer I've received on SO, I wish I could upvote a couple more times!